# How to enable ehcache statistics on spring xml file

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

Based on following configuration I cannot enable ehcache statistics on xml file. There is no such a property to enable ehcache statistics.

```
<bean id="cache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
  <property name="cacheName" value="diskCache"/>
  <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
  <property name="maxElementsInMemory" value="1"/>
  <property name="overflowToDisk" value="true"/>
  <property name="maxElementsOnDisk" value="10"/>
</bean>
```

Ehcache 2.4.6 comes with disabled cache statistics.

Has anyone else had experience implementing this?

Any help or ideas on this would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the built-in `EhCacheFactoryBean` does not support setting this flag (I encourage you to open a [feature request](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR)). However it is relatively easy to add this by yourself:

```
package com.example;

public class EhCacheWithStatisticsFactoryBean extends EhCacheFactoryBean {

    private boolean statisticsEnabled;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws CacheException, IOException {
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
        getObject().setStatisticsEnabled(statisticsEnabled);
    }

    public void setStatisticsEnabled(boolean statisticsEnabled) {
        this.statisticsEnabled = statisticsEnabled;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
<bean id="cache" class="com.example.EhCacheWithStatisticsFactoryBean">
  <property name="cacheName" value="diskCache"/>
  <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
  <property name="maxElementsInMemory" value="1"/>
  <property name="overflowToDisk" value="true"/>
  <property name="maxElementsOnDisk" value="10"/>
  <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true"/> <!-- HERE -->
</bean>
```

Of course the easy path would be to use standard `ehcache.xml` file.

Comment: Spring 3.1 RC1 will come new feature https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8855?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel